# How to set the number of virtual desktops in PIXEL / create new vdesktops?

Tags: raspbian

I've been looking everywhere to answer this simple question:
How to set the number of virtual desktops in PIXEL / create new vdesktops?
But could not find any answer.
I've found a reference to a similar question asked here, but apparently it was removed. Why, I'll never know????
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57900/setting-the-number-of-desktops-in-pixel

Indeed, as a linux/bsd user for years, a WM/DE that has only a single virtual desktop is simply unusable for me. I *need* multiple desktops.

Does anyone know how I could create say 4 vdesktops in PIXEL? Or should I consider using another WM/DE (that would be a pitty, PIXEL is simple and pretty, I like it)?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. That question you're refering to was automatically (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/284388)) deleted (and whether that makes any sense is irrelevant to your question). I'd rather remove the link as it does not contribute anything to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `obconf`

1. Install by running `sudo apt install obconf`.
2. Run with `obconf`.
3. Open up the `Desktop` tab.
4. Input the number of desktops that you want to have into the `Number of Desktops` area.